# Access value from dynamically loaded input fields

Tags: javascript

Trying access the values from dynamic generated input fields and put this in a field 'result'. By default the webpage shows one input field. When type in this field (Naam 1), the value from this field, gets into the result field, so this works perfect!
But when type '3' in the input field 'Number fields', this generate 3 input fields:

- NAAM 1 (class=naamveld-1)
- NAAM 2 (class=naamveld-2)
- NAAM 3 (class=naamveld-3)

```
<div class="container">
Naam 1<input type="text" class="naamveld-1"><br>
Naam 2<input type="text" class="naamveld-2"><br>
Naam 3<input type="text" class="naamveld-3"><br>
</div>
```

When type text in this fields, then there is nothing shows up in the Result Field.

The webpage incl. source code can find here (right click -> view source):
https://webkusthosting.be/js/

I'm not an advanced JS programmer, so i hope someone can help me with this?

Comment: @Barmar
Searching a lot on Stackoverflow and indeed find several questions, but not for my specific problem. Searching hours found a solution but doesn't find it, also not on this website! Is it duplicate question? YES and NO!!!

Comment: Why do you have to search? I marked it as a duplicate of a specific question, doesn't it have the answer?

Comment: Okay, now i understand what you mean, sorry about that. btw, yesterday i found a solution for my problem. Not find it here on Stackoverflow, but trial and error!